# GWT: Disable middle mouse button scroll for firefox

Tags: css, firefox, gwt

I made in GWT custom modal message box. It has also bottom layer. This means that I expect restriction of any user action at the page except clicking 'Ok'.

I made something like [this](http://examples.roughian.com/#Widgets~DialogBox) (click on the 'show dialog box').

I have made bottom layer that covers all bottom controls. It has style:

```
.glass {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.50;
    -moz-opacity: 0.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But the problem that in firefox user can click middle mouse button and scroll away, to the area that bottom layer will not cover.

In GWT i disabled scroll. It helps in IE, but not in FF.

```
Window.enableScrolling( false );
```

How to disable middle mouse scroll for short time?
Or i can make CSS for panel that will cover also hidden page area?

Thanks for any help!
and Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [GlassPanel](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GlassPanel) in the [Google Web Toolkit Incubator](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/) - you might get some ideas from there (they didn't solve/restrict the middle button, just extended the panel to cover the whole page, including the hidden area).